# How to check if DNS entries exists in resolv.conf file in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I'm new to Ansible and I want to check if IP addresses are in *resolv.conf* file is in the following series *2.9.10.X* or *2.9.11.X* to print a debug message: "DNS entries exists" and if not in the above series then update resolv.conf file with the following data:

```
nameserver 2.9.10.X  
nameserver 2.9.11.X 
nameserver 2.366.5.60
```

So far I made it up to this :

```
- name: check resolv.conf file exists
  stat:
    path: /etc/resolv.conf
  register: resolv_conf

- name: print a debug message when resolf.config file does not exists
  debug:
    msg: "The resolv.conf path doesn't exist."
  when: resolv_conf.stat.exists == False

- name: check nameservers list in resolv.conf
  debug:
    msg: "{{ contents }}"
  vars:
    contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf') | regex_findall('\\s*nameserver\\s*(.*)') }}"
  when: resolv_conf.stat.exists == True
  register: "{{ contents }}"
```

Is there is anyway I can add to check if IP addresses are in series *2.9.10.X* or *2.9.11.X* to this line:

```
 contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf') | regex_findall('\\s*nameserver\\s*(.*)') }}"
```

If not, what will be the best solution to continue from here. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered instead of checking the current state of the file, to just overwrite the file regardless. For example, using the `copy` module to send a static resolv.conf. Or more flexibly template out resolv.conf and use the `template` module.

Comment: @Rickkwa  thanks for the advice I'll look into it too. I was giving the above order by the Lead Engineer.